# Mencionar código HTML em post do Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou escrevendo um novo post no Wordpress, esse post dou vários exemplos de códigos HTML aonde eu explico todo o comportamento da página HTML.

O problema é que o Wordpress permite que os textos dos posts sejam escritos e formatados com tags HTML, dessa forma eu não consigo colocar um exemplo de uma página HTML. Já tentei **<code>** e **```html** (do Markdown).

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código HTML abaixo:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Java Magazine</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 id="titulo">Java Magazine - Integração Contínua</h1>
            <h2 id="sub-titulo">Usuários</h2>
            <hr>

            <form class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID"/>
                </div>
                <button id="btn-buscar-id" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">ID</button>
                <button id="btn-buscar-todos" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Todos</button>
                <button id="btn-limpar" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Limpar</button>
            </form>

            <br><br>

            <table id="tabela" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-xs-1"> #</th>
                    <th class="col-xs-11"> Nome</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tabela-resultado"></tbody>
            </table>

            <p id="erro" class="bg-warning">Nenhum registro encontrado!</p>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

A tag que abre o formulário,  até o final da  dentro do fomulário somem do texto, o texto volta a aparecer nos .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi seguindo parcialmente a dica do @henriquedpereira, que me passou a URL: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts

Para resolver eu inseri o código HTML dentro da tag *```html* e substitui os caracteres <, > e / conforme tabela mencionada no link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts#List_of_Related_Character_Entities

Segue o código:

```
    &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
    &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
        &lt;title&gt;Integração Contínua&lt;&#47;title&gt;
        &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="http:&#47;&#47;maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com&#47;bootstrap&#47;3.3.5&#47;css&#47;bootstrap.min.css"&gt;
    &lt;&#47;head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
    &lt;div class="container"&gt;
        &lt;h1 id="titulo"&gt;Integração Contínua&lt;&#47;h1&gt;
        &lt;h2 id="sub-titulo"&gt;Usuários&lt;&#47;h2&gt;
        &lt;hr&gt;

        &lt;form class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false"&gt;
            &lt;div class="form-group"&gt;
                &lt;input id="id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID"&#47;&gt;
            &lt;&#47;div&gt;
            &lt;button id="btn-buscar-id" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"&gt;ID&lt;&#47;button&gt;
            &lt;button id="btn-buscar-todos" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"&gt;Todos&lt;&#47;button&gt;
            &lt;button id="btn-limpar" class="btn btn-danger" type="button"&gt;Limpar&lt;&#47;button&gt;
        &lt;&#47;form&gt;

        &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;

        &lt;table id="tabela" class="table table-hover"&gt;
            &lt;thead&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;th class="col-xs-1"&gt; #&lt;&#47;th&gt;
                &lt;th class="col-xs-11"&gt; Nome&lt;&#47;th&gt;
            &lt;&#47;tr&gt;
            &lt;&#47;thead&gt;
            &lt;tbody id="tabela-resultado"&gt;&lt;&#47;tbody&gt;
        &lt;&#47;table&gt;

        &lt;p id="erro" class="bg-warning"&gt;Nenhum registro encontrado!&lt;&#47;p&gt;
    &lt;&#47;div&gt;
    &lt;&#47;body&gt;
    &lt;&#47;html&gt;
```

Comment: Legal, coloca seu código editado para vermos também.

Answer (score 3):

Usa `<code></code>`

Da uma olhada em: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts

Comment: Henrique segui lá e consegui. Abaixo a resposta de como eu consegui resolver o problema. 

Obrigado!!!